# How to restrict a remote coldfusion function from being called directly? (AJAX)

Tags: jquery, ajax, security, coldfusion, csrf

I have a Coldfusion server with several applications.  Many of these applications use a generic set of component functions for both server-side rendering and AJAX calls. Let's call this generic component file:

```
serverfunctions.cfc
```

These functions are stored in a folder separate from other applications, although the component files in each of these applications (cf)include the generic component file as a template.  Let's call these app-specific component file:

```
appfunctions.cfc
```

AJAX requests go to appfunctions.cfc even if they are for methods in serverfunctions.cfc.  This cuts down on redundant code and also allows me to check for CSRF attacks in the application.cfc OnRequestStart method before processing the AJAX request.

### However...

I would like to enforce a requirement that EVERY AJAX request has to go through the appfunctions.cfc component, and serverfunctions.cfc CANNOT be called directly from the client.  This way, other programmers on this codebase are prevented from "accidentally" setting up AJAX calls without proper CSRF protection.

So far I have tried to adjust the access attribute on the remote functions but that only returns "403 - Forbidden".

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  The rule is that any "remote" method in a web-accessible CFC will be available to call from a remote client.  I'd tell you to change the access away from remote, but you said yourself that you call these functions directly from the client so this seems like a catch 22.

Comment: not sure what you need exactly, but fyi there's `onCfcRequest` that may do what you need.

Comment: @BradWood I want the client to only be able to call the methods in serverfunctions.cfc via appfunctions.cfc, but not serverfunctions.cfc directly.  So far that is how the system is designed (you CAN call serverfunctions.cfc directly but all code written so far calls those functions indirectly via appfunctions.cfc), but there is nothing stopping another developer from calling serverfunctions.cfc directly, even though adhering to our best practices would require they route all AJAX calls through appfunctions.cfc

Comment: @Henry I looked into onCfcRequest, but it doesn't provide much more functionality than I already have with my preemptive onRequestStart, and since the components in serverfunctions.cfc are stateless and have no knowledge of the outside system, onCfcRequest doesn't help me with the CSRF token issue.

Comment: Have the serverfunctions.cfc methods return structs, queries, etc - things that have to be processed further to make them js friendly.   In your appfunctions.cfc, write methods to do that processing.

Comment: @DanBracuk I thought about it, but I am trying to reduce the amount of redundant code I have to maintain.  This system supports dozens of sites across several developers and it gets hard to track which states of development they are in.  As it stands, I have zero lines of additional code in various appfunctions.cfc files to support serverfunctions.cfc (aside from cfinclude).  Keeping it at zero also keeps any associated headaches at zero.

Comment: I don't see the functions.  What I conceive as possible though, is to reduce the amount of redundant code - the code that makes ColdFusion data suitable for exporting to javascript.  Plus, the fact that you mentioned `cfinclude` when talking about 2 cfc's makes me raise my eyebrows.

Comment: If you don't want people calling serverfunction's methods directly, then just extend it properly with appfunctions and override the methods! Take off the "remote" from the parent class, and call it with super.method();  Unless you have specific logic in appfunctions, what's the issue with people calling the base class methods??  I think maybe your messing stuff up by cfincluding instead of extending.

Comment: I nominate @BradWood's comment to be the answer.

Comment: @BradWood I combined your comment and a Ben Nadel blog post into a usable framework.  I wrote it up into an answer, although I need to wait a day until I can accept my own answer. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing inspiration from @BradWood's comments, I have come to an answer.

**tl;dr: Create a server mapping for the serverfunctions folder and extend it from the appfunctions component.**

As stated in the question, my goal is to force AJAX calls for server-level functions through application-level components to enforce a preemptive CSRF token check (which has to be done at the application-session level and keeps the server-level functions totally stateless), while keeping redundant code per-application down to a minimum.

A blog post by Ben Nadel helped bring this all together: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2115-extending-the-application-cfc-coldfusion-framework-component-with-a-relative-path-proxy.htm

Here is a code example:

**server/serverfunctionsfolder/serverfunctions.cfc**

```
<CFCOMPONENT>
<cffunction name="getAHatForYourCat" access="package" returntype="string" returnformat="plain">
  <cfargument name="cat" type="string" required="yes" default="cat">
  <cfreturn cat & " and a hat.">
</cffunction>
</CFCOMPONENT>
```

**server/app/appfunctions.cfc**

```
<CFCOMPONENT extends="/serverfunctionsfolder/serverfunctions">
<cffunction name="getAHatForYourCat" access="remote" returntype="string" returnformat="plain">
  <cfargument name="cat" type="string" required="yes" default="cat">
  <cfreturn Super.getAHatForYourCat(cat)>
</cffunction>
</CFCOMPONENT>
```

**server/app/Application.cfc (OPTIONAL-ISH)**

(This depends on how you want to do it.  You can create a mapping in application.cfc as shown below for this example, although I ultimately made the mapping in the ColdFusion administrator.)

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart">
    <cfset this.mappings['/serverfunctionsfolder'] = ExpandPath("../serverfunctionsfolder/")>
</cffunction>
```

**server/app/appscript.js**

```
function getACatAndAHat(cat)
{
  var saveUrl = "components/appfunctions.cfc?method=getAHatForYourCat";
  var saveData = {};
  saveData['cat'] = cat;
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: saveUrl,
    data: saveData
  }).done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }).fail(function(data) {
     alert("Get a hat for your cat failed");
   });  
}

// Method call with this argument returns "A cat and a hat."
getACatAndAHat("A cat");
```

I did not include the code to generate an anti-CSRF token, prepend it to AJAX requests, or validate the token with OnRequestStart because implementations may vary and it isn't entirely relevant to the question or answer.

Comment: Why can't appfunctions just extend serverfunctions directly?  What's the purpose of the intermediate include?  Also, you're also not even referencing the super method in that example so what you're trying to do isn't clear.

Comment: @BradWood Edited a minute before you commented. Anyway, appfunctions cannot extend serverfunctions directly because serverfunctions is in a different directory.  appfunctions cannot include serverfunctions directly because coldfusion throws a "Routines cannot be declared more than once" error. Hopefully this helps.  I will incorporate it into a further edit.  Please let me know if there is anything else confusing for the sake of future folks.

Comment: A CFC can most certainly extend another from another directory.  You simply need the full component path, creating a mapping if necessary.  Inheritance should never throw that error either.  Are you confusing inheritance (the extends annotation) with cfinclude?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: I tried using extends with the full path, but the AJAX call responds with "Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface /www/serverfolder/serverfunctions/serverfunctions"  While I did consider mapping as an alternative, I found it to be too confusing and workaround-y to have to deal with, and since extending the appwrapper which cfincludes the serverfunctions only adds an additional three lines of code, I found that to be the best solution.  But if you have a simpler one, I'm all ears.

Comment: @DanBracuk I updated the answer to work with mappings.  Hopefully it will mean you can reverse your downvote, since a future programmer might be discouraged from a correct answer because of your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Ths is how a secondary, outside non-accessible function is set up:

```
<cffunction name="select" access="package" output="false" returnType="array">
```

This should give error: 
**The method 'select' in component D:/wwwroot/mywebsite/restapi/v1/comp.cfc cannot be accessed remotely.**

This is how I access that protected function from REST cfc

```
<cfinvoke component="comp" method="select" returnVariable="myobj">
    <cfinvokeargument name="scRow" value="#scRow#">
</cfinvoke>
```

Comment: I tried using access="package" but I got that error whether I called the function from serverfunctions.cfc or appfunctions.cfc.  Indeed, it was that failure that resulted in my turning to StackOverflow to ask this question.

Comment: I have this set up and it works... Are you using cfinvoke? Here's how I'm calling it:
<cfinvoke component="comp" method="select" returnVariable="dbmsg">
<cfinvokeargument name="shoppingCartRow" value="#myobj#">
</cfinvoke>

Comment: Just so I know for sure, are you saying that you are able to call the method remotely from a file that includes the method's file, but not when you call the method from the method's file itself?

Comment: I am not using cfinvoke.  This is purely an issue with AJAX POST requests made with jQuery.

Comment: I
t's 2 different files. cfinvoke is in the REST API cfc and cffunction is in another cfc. One more thing, I keep both CFCs in the same directory...

Comment: If you aren't using cfinvoke, how are you calling functions from another cfc? Just as it is, i.e. #myfucntion(var)#?

Comment: The files are in separate directories.  serverroot/app/appfunctions.cfc cfincludes serverroot/serverfunctions/serverfunctions.cfc but I use jQuery's $.ajax function to call methods in appfunctions.cfc, even though the actual methods are in serverfunctions.cfc (ex: $.ajax({url:'appfunctions/appfunctions.cfc?method=genericservermethod'});

 Your solution is correct, but not for my particular situation, unfortunately.